# Good way to sanitize incoming JSON data from XSS in PHP

Tags: php, json, wordpress, xss

I have a php function that does this to escape HTML tags using wordpress's esc_attr function but I am having to covert the JSON data to an array and then back to an object, anyway to map a function directly to an object?

```
function get_ajax_data() {
    $data = (object) array_map('esc_attr', json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true ));
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having here? Are you worried about the performance of casting to an object? It isn't a particularly slow operation.

Comment: Generally I think its a good idea to store the data in as raw a format as possible and then filter on the way back out of the db to prevent xss (with the exception of sql injection filtering) then you will have a record of what the attacker attempted

Comment: Yes speed, and I was wondering if this is the best way of doing it.

Comment: Why even decode the JSON?  Just escape the string.

Comment: @ Deryck could you please give an example of want you mean? I am using the data as follows e.g.  $data = get_ajax_data(); $data->interview_id

Comment: You do not *have* to use `array_map()`. You can just use a `foreach` loop and be done with it...